# trentrichardson datetimepicker and timepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

For the trentrichardson timepicker addon (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) for datetimepicker and timepicker, it seems to work for a limited amount of time (6 hours to a day), THEN, it stops working. TO FIX THIS, I replace the addon CDN (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js), for the same one, and it works again.

How could this be? I put the CDN's in the correct order as well...

1. jQuery
2. jQueryUI (with datepicker and slider wigits)
3. Timepicker
4. Then CSS

P.S. I removed my main.css file and corresponding class="" from the inputs.

Once again, it works for 6 hours to a day, then stops working... with nothing changing. And I'm pretty sure the CDN's are not changing either, but they may be, but that should not matter since the file path itself is not changing. Let me know what you think, thanks! ALSO, when it stops working, I checked the file paths and they are still valid.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">

<script> 
$(function() {
    $( "#datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker();
});

$(function() {
    $( "#timepicker" ).timepicker();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php
echo '<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" size="12px">';
echo '<input type="text" id="timepicker" size="2px">';
?>
```

Comment: I don't believe `trentrichardson.com` is a CDN - he hosts his demos there. Can you not host these locally, or at least have a fallback mechanism? Have you looked at http://www.jsdelivr.com/ or similar?

Comment: @wirey you mean the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> twice? I deleted the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> and it still works. So that might be it.

Comment: @mccannf I don't see why I can't use http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js as a CDN though. If I copy what is there into a js text file, how would that not be the same thing? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below. It looks like Trent is taking steps to block such activity ;)

Answer (score 4):

Trent Richardson has explicitly started preventing hotlinks to his site as of last year:

http://trentrichardson.com/2012/09/27/no-more-hotlinking/

Your hotlinks may only work sporadically, or may not work at all.

You should use [jsdeliver.com](http://jsdeliver.com) (which hosts his timepicker plugin) or find another CDN.

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually the jsdeliver has version 1.2 and it doesn't seem to work. For now I'll just dl 1.3 and save it locally.